# Why does this synchronized program returns wrong results?

Tags: java, synchronization

In order to understand how Java synchronization works, I wrote a simple sample program that calculates the sum of an array using four threads. I know it is not very efficient, but it seems that it should work since I use a lock:

```
public class ConcurrencyTest1 {

    static Object lock = new Object();
    static volatile int sum;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[40000];
        Arrays.fill(array, 1);

        sum = 0;

        new Thread( ()-> {
            for (int i=0;i<10000;++i)
                synchronized(lock) {
                    sum += array[i];
                }
        } ).start();

        new Thread( ()-> {
            for (int i=10000;i<20000;++i) 
                synchronized(lock) {
                    sum += array[i];
                }
        } ).start();

        new Thread( ()-> {
            for (int i=20000;i<30000;++i) 
                synchronized(lock) {
                    sum += array[i];
                }
        } ).start();

        for (int i=30000;i<40000;++i) 
            synchronized(lock) {
                sum += array[i];
            }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }

}
```

The correct answer is 40000. However, when I run it many times, I often get smaller numbers such as 37713 or 30000. Why?

Comment: You don't `join` any of the threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `main` program thread starts 4 threads and then prints sum. It does not wait for these threads to finish their work. Minimal changes to make it work would be:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(()-> {
   for (int i=0;i<10000;++i)
      synchronized(lock) {
          sum += array[i];
      }
});
...
t1.start();
....

t1.join();
...
t4.join();

System.out.println(sum);
```